# Compare upper cell with lower cell in power query with if & AND condition

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Can anyone suggest me how to write this formula (which is shown in image) in Powerquery.
The code which i wrote is

```
if [Date]<>[previous Date] and [Hrs Reg]<>0 then "No"else if [FinalStatus]="Yes" and [#"G/H"]<=0.08 then "No" else null
```

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to add an index column and use that to find the "previous" row in the data set. One example: [PowerBI Community](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Referencing-a-previous-Row/td-p/477748). Why is this tagged as VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [previous Date], do you mean the previous cell [Date]?

If so, you need to create two index columns, one starting from 1 (you can name it **Index**), and another starting from 0 (this will be your **Previous**).

This way you have a corresponding value between the current row and the previous one.

Next, you can **Merge** the table with itself, using the columns **Index** and **Previous**.

After that, you can expand the new table, select the [Date] column, and this will put the previous date in the same row.

The final step is what you already have, just replace [previous Date] with that new expanded [Date], that is actually the previous date.

For reference and better explanation, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xN2IRXQ2CvI) by Matt Allington.

Comment: Thank you soo much Dreekun, your Answer helped a lot and that worked fine. Thank you soo much.

Comment: hsan: Sorry for Tagging this for VBA. Since i'm working on VBA code with the combination of Power query, so i tagged it as VBA.